# LaTeX script to tile mutiple images into a single figure

Tags: subcaption

I'm looking to devise a way to tile multiple images into the single figure in LaTeX.

I currently have the code below which works when the images fit nicely into a grid

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

% Sub-Figure Example
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.9\textwidth}

% Figure row 1
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{coffee.jpg}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} A}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{coffee.jpg}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} B}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{coffee.jpg}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} C}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{coffee.jpg}
    \put (1.5,48) {\color{white} D}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\caption{This is a figure. \subref{fig:a} This is a cup of coffee. 
  \subref{fig:b} This is another cup of coffee. \subref{fig:c} This is more coffee.  
  \subref{fig:d} This is a big cup of coffee.}
\label{fig:coffee3}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

This, however, doesn't seem to work where the images need to span columns. Such as when one or more images is in a different orientation.  It also assumes all images have the same aspect ratio.

For example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

% Sub-Figure Example
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.9\textwidth}

% Figure row 1
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[abs,unit=1mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (3,23) {\color{white} A}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[abs,unit=1mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (3,23) {\color{white} B}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[abs,unit=1mm,width=\textwidth,angle=90]{example-image}
    \put (3,23) {\color{white} C}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[abs,unit=1mm,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (3,80) {\color{white} D}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\caption{This is a figure caption \subref{fig:a} This is a subfigure. 
  \subref{fig:b} This is another subfigure. \subref{fig:c} This is yet another subfigure.  
  \subref{fig:d} This is a big subfigure.}
\label{fig:coffee3}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about what your question is? What were you hoping would happen instead? Should you perhaps be using `height=\textwidth` for the third image?

Comment: Sorry I’ll try to revise my post.  The problem I’m trying to solve is that it’s typical for me to need to arrange a handful of sub figures it a single image.  I usually do this in photoshop and then typeset as a single figure but apply subcaptions.  I’m trying to determine if there’s a elegant way to avoid laying out the single image in photoshop and have latex combine the images as a single figure / sub figure in an elegant fashion overlying labels on each.  The key is that often the constituent parts are not the same aspect ratios.